# Rails equivalent active record query for SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How can I write a rails4 active record equivalent query for the following MySQL query?

```
SELECT c.id,c.account_name,sum(i.balance) as balance from clients c, invoices i 
where c.id = i.client_id GROUP BY  c.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Client.joins(:invoices).select('clients.id, clients.account_name, sum(invoices.balance) as balance').group('clients.id')`

Comment: Is it possible to write  query with out join?

Comment: `Client.joins(:invoices)` is equivalent to `from clients c, invoices i 
where c.id = i.client_id`.

Comment: But you can also use the `find_by_sql` method: `Clients.find_by_sql "SELECT c.id,c.account_name,sum(i.balance) as balance from clients c, invoices i where c.id = i.client_id GROUP BY  c.id"` should work.